# Create a new generation using replication and crossover in genetic algorthm

Tags: replication, genetic-algorithm

Hi all i am studying genetic algorithm to create a new generation. I got a problem for the following one:

This question refers to Genetic Algorithms. Assume you have a population made of 10 individuals. Each individual is made of 5 bits. Here is the initial population.

```
x1 = (1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
x2 = (1, 1, 0, 0, 1)
x3 = (1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
x4 = (1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
x5 = (0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
x6 = (0, 0, 1, 1, 1)
x7 = (0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
x8 = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
x9 = (1, 0, 1, 1, 1)
x10 = (1, 0, 0, 1, 0)
```

Individuals are ranked according to fitness value (x1 has the greatest fitness value, x2 the second best, etc.). Assume that when sampling, you get individuals in the same order as they are ranked. Create a new generation of solutions assuming the following:

Replication is 20%. Cross over is 80% (assume a crossover mask as follows: 11100; pair examples in the same order as ranked). No mutation is done.

My solution: replication is 20% that means first two population is unchanged.Next the given the crossover mask given 11100 I choose randomly 3 words from crossover(11100) mask so start from x3 and x4 and here i keep first 3 words same both x3 and x4 and finally swap last two remaining words for x3 and x4 and generate new population. I follow same rule for x5 and x6, x7 and x8 and x9 and x10.I am not sure this answer is correct or wrong. Any body can help me please?

Comment: 20% replication means that 20% of your individuals will take part in the recombination (crossover in your case). I understand the crossover mask as the crossover point being between bit1 and bit2 (single-point crossover, bit enumeration is (4,3,2,1,0) ). This means you take bit2-4 from one individual and swap them with bit2-4 from another to create your offspring.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the background of the implementation you are using so I may not be correct, but from a genetic algorithm point of view most of your answer seems correct.

As far as I can see, the only issue in your reasoning is with the crossover. After replication has taken place you use the remaining chromosomes for crossover. This seems inherently flawed from a genetic algorithms point of view. Genetic algorithms generally use the best chromosome in crossover. You've already saved the best and seem to then exclude them from any recombination. This idea goes against the idea of genetic algorithms, which is to evolve the population by means of recombination of the fittest individuals. At the very least, the fittest chromosomes should be included.

Generally, most implementations involve an element of randomness in selection with the fittest chromosomes given more weighting. Since your question explicitly states that pairs are selected in order of ranking, and therefore no randomness, I'd assume crossover is to be performed on chromosomes 1 to 8.

Your understanding of the crossover mask seems correct from the question.

Again, I know nothing of the implementation in question so I'm not sure how good my understanding is. I'd be interested to know the source since the genetic algorithm seems highly unusual.